# Breaking a given string into dictionary words

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing

Am trying to break a given string into dictionary words from a given dictionary and find all such possible sets.
Ex.: if given word is “programmerit”, then output shall be:
{{pro, gram, merit}, {program, merit}, {programmer, it}}

My below solution, works in exponential time. O(c^n); where is c is some constant I haven't evaluated and n is the size (characters) of given word.
I am trying to reduce the complexity or maybe bring it down to a lower exponent, but to no avail. Looking for any suggestions in this regard.

PS: this is not a homework or assignment problem, I am a working professional and trying this out of curiosity.

Here is my code:

```
bool isContained(string word, string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (i >= word.length())
            return false;
        if (word[i] != s[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    void getParts(vector<string> dict, string word, stack<string> s, vector<vector<string> > &parts) {
        if (word.length() == 0) {
            if (s.size() > 0) {
                vector<string> part;
                stack<string> t = s;
                while(!t.empty()) {
                    part.push_back(t.top());
                    t.pop();
                }
                parts.push_back(part);
            }
        } else {
            int j = find_starting_ind(dict, word[0]);
            int ct = j;
            while (dict[ct][0] == word[0]) {
                if (isContained(word, dict[ct])) {
                    s.push(dict[ct]);
                    string nword = word-dict[ct];
                    getParts(dict, nword, s, parts);
                    s.pop();
                }
                ct++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider what is the size of the output for dictionary={a,aa,aaa,...,aaa..a} and word aaaa...a

Comment: Try using a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store your dictionary